# edits to clusterrole "view" are not persisted in aws eks?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-rbac

```
aggregationRule:
  clusterRoleSelectors:
  - matchLabels:
      rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-18T01:09:33Z"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
  name: view
  resourceVersion: "26982828"
  uid: 9ccd7ac4-0660-47a8-b1cd-8282df11d23d
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - cert-manager.io
  resources:
  - certificates
  - certificaterequests
  - issuers
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - acme.cert-manager.io
  resources:
  - challenges
  - orders
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - endpoints
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - persistentvolumeclaims/status
  - pods
  - replicationcontrollers
  - replicationcontrollers/scale
  - serviceaccounts
  - services
  - services/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - bindings
  - events
  - limitranges
  - namespaces/status
  - pods/log
  - pods/status
  - replicationcontrollers/status
  - resourcequotas
  - resourcequotas/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - controllerrevisions
  - daemonsets
  - daemonsets/status
  - deployments
  - deployments/scale
  - deployments/status
  - replicasets
  - replicasets/scale
  - replicasets/status
  - statefulsets
  - statefulsets/scale
  - statefulsets/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - autoscaling
  resources:
  - horizontalpodautoscalers
  - horizontalpodautoscalers/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - cronjobs
  - cronjobs/status
  - jobs
  - jobs/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - daemonsets
  - daemonsets/status
  - deployments
  - deployments/scale
  - deployments/status
  - ingresses
  - ingresses/status
  - networkpolicies
  - replicasets
  - replicasets/scale
  - replicasets/status
  - replicationcontrollers/scale
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resources:
  - poddisruptionbudgets
  - poddisruptionbudgets/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  - ingresses/status
  - networkpolicies
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - tekton.dev
  resources:
  - tasks
  - taskruns
  - pipelines
  - pipelineruns
  - pipelineresources
  - conditions
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - triggers.tekton.dev
  resources:
  - clustertriggerbindings
  - clusterinterceptors
  - eventlisteners
  - triggers
  - triggerbindings
  - triggertemplates
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

then I'm adding entries in it

```
- apiGroups:
  - argoproj.io
  resources:
  - application
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

```
➜ k edit clusterrole view
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/view edited
```

but then when I edit it again - these entries are gone, how to add them? It seems this role is purely dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

ok fixed it by adding a separated clusterrole with specific label

```
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
```

full code:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: argocd-aggregate-view
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"  
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - argoproj.io
  resources:
  - applications
  - appprojects
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer why changes in default `view` role do not persist. Also I can see `tekton`, so somehow there changes can get into this role. So it's correctly to say `workaround` rather than `fix`.

Comment: So this is aggregated role, i.e. dynamic. To add the value - you should make a role with the annotation per my answer. Tekton is there, because there is another aggregation role created by tekton helm chart.